# Crontab can't create logs (Permission Denied)

Tags: cron, logfiles

I have a script that I want to run every hour, and the `echo`'s of that script and other output, I want to be able to read.

Now when I take a look at `/var/log/syslog`, I see some weird stuff that I can't explain. Please see below.

Would anyone know what my issue is?

```
Apr 29 22:52:01 raspberrypi cron[408]: (pi) RELOAD (crontabs/pi)
Apr 29 22:52:01 raspberrypi CRON[8189]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/Projects/test-cron.sh)
Apr 29 22:52:01 raspberrypi cron[408]: 2022-04-29 22:52:01 1nkXar-000288-H2 Cannot open main log file "/var/log/exim4/mainlog": Permission denied: euid=112 egid=119
Apr 29 22:52:01 raspberrypi cron[408]: 2022-04-29 22:52:01 1nkXar-000288-H2 <= pi@raspberrypi U=pi P=local S=575
Apr 29 22:52:01 raspberrypi cron[408]: 2022-04-29 22:52:01 1nkXar-000288-H2 Cannot open main log file "/var/log/exim4/mainlog": Permission denied: euid=112 egid=119
Apr 29 22:52:01 raspberrypi cron[408]: exim: could not open panic log - aborting: see message(s) above
Apr 29 22:52:01 raspberrypi exim[8192]: 2022-04-29 22:52:01 1nkXar-000288-H2 <= pi@raspberrypi U=pi P=local S=575
Apr 29 22:52:01 raspberrypi exim[8192]: 2022-04-29 22:52:01 1nkXar-000288-H2 Cannot open main log file "/var/log/exim4/mainlog": Permission denied: euid=112 egid=119
Apr 29 22:52:01 raspberrypi exim[8192]: exim: could not open panic log - aborting: see message(s) above
Apr 29 22:52:01 raspberrypi CRON[8188]: (pi) MAIL (mailed 6 bytes of output but got status 0x0001 from MTA#012)
```

I have no idea what exim4 is, I never installed this. I just wanna see some logs from my cron jobs.

More information about my setup:

`crontab -e`

```
# Thanks to https://linuxhint.com/check_working_crontab/
# I know this is not every hour; this is just an example to make the job run frequently!
* * * * * /home/pi/Projects/test-cron.sh
```

`ls -la in /home/pi/Projects`

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 pi   pi   4096 Apr 29 22:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 pi   pi   4096 Apr 29 01:24 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pi   pi     13 Apr 29 22:39 test-cron.sh
```

`test-cron.sh`

```
echo "TESTING CRONJOBS!"
```

---

Now, I would expect if I did something like `cat /var/log/syslog | grep "TESTING CRONJOBS!"`, I would see the results... But I don't!

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, there are two  problems: `exim` and `cron`.

Exim is mail.
The message:

```
log file "/var/log/exim4/mainlog": Permission denied: euid=112 egid=119
```

gives you the reason why `exim` will not start. As a quick fix, you could

```
chown -R 112 /var/log/exim4
```

Cron sends standard-out to the mail, not to the syslog. Because your mail is aborting, you never get this mail. If you want to log to the syslog, use `logger`, as in

```
logger "TESTING CRONJOBS works in this way"
```

Answer (score 3):

The `bullseye` distribution introduced many changes to `cron`. If you've used `cron` previously - or on other distributions - you will need to acquaint yourself with these changes which have *flowed down* to Raspberry Pi OS from Debian. If you're running `bullseye`, it can be said that you are now running the *Debian version* of `cron`. It's not altogether different, but there are some changes you should be aware of.

If you're new to `cron`, this is all new anyway, so don't worry :)

##### *Take Note:*

Unless you actually ***prefer*** to get your `cron` outputs via email, you should add the following line to your user `crontab`:

```
MAILTO=""
```

***Why do this?*** To disable `cron`'s default behavior for mailing output to the owner of the `crontab`. See REFERENCE # 1 below.

##### *How can I read the output of my `cron` jobs?*

The *typical way* this is done is to use the `redirection` operators that are a part of `sh` - the default shell used in `cron`. Using your `cron` job as an example, this is how it's done:

```
* * * * * /home/pi/Projects/test-cron.sh >> /home/pi/Projects/test-cron.log 2>&1
```

Let's break this down:

1. `>> /home/pi/Projects/test-cron.log` redirects the output of your script to the named file (it can be any name you choose). `>>` is the ***append*** form of the redirect - meaning that each time it writes to the file, a line is *added*; i.e. your file will grow large over time. You can also use the ***overwrite*** form of the redirect: `>`. In this case, your file will only contain the *last* line that was redirected to it.
2. `2>&1` is also a form of redirect - it causes the `stderr` (`2`) output to redirect to `stdout` (`1`). Yes - the syntax may look strange, but it won't seem strange at all after using it a while. What it ***does*** is to combine both types of output from your script (stdout & stderr) so that ***both*** wind up in your `test-cron.log` file.

You may find this a bit easier than dealing with a mail client, and/or revising permissions on MTA servers with potentially *unintended consequences*.

##### REFERENCE 1. From `man 5 crontab`:

> If MAILTO is defined (and non-empty), mail is sent to the user so named.  MAILTO may also be used to direct mail to multiple recipients by separating recipient users with a comma.  If MAILTO is defined but empty  (MAILTO=""),
> no mail will be sent.  Otherwise mail is sent to the owner of the crontab.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for your amazing answer. Super useful and detailed; others should take inspiration from this!

Comment: @S.tenBrinke: Glad it helped. [Please read this.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)